# Loop xldown many times

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is loop `xlDown` multiple times

I have in mind something like this:

```
For i=1 to 2000

   1 x Selection.End(xlDown).Select
then copy a range, then pasting it in another worksheet (i already have these functions)

next
```

The second iteration should do `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` 2 times, the third 3 times and so on.

Please, I'm stuck with this one and I know it's very easy

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you want to copy data many times? isn't one time enough?

Comment: No. I want to do it multiple times to batch copy a large amount of data which has some holes in between

Comment: Are you just trying to copy the range starting from a certain row down to the last used row?  Do you want the "holes" copied as well, or just the non-blank rows?

Comment: xldown goes to I11 (the first one), then the macro goes 8 columns to the right, copies, goes 8 to the left then pastes that value in another sheet in the last column of the first row

The next value i want to offset copy is I284, then I286 and so on. All those cells are or not between holes. I can select all the values I'm interested in via CTRL+Down, that's why i used  xldown.

The difficulty here is that when I want to return to the first sheet after pasting it I don't know how to go back to the last copied row, so I used a fixed reference (X9) and then xldown it multiple times

Comment: is that data compiled on one column? because if that's the case, maybe determining last row by xlUp method will suffice. For Example `Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").end(xlUp).row).Copy`

Comment: No. What I want to do is copy only the values that have holes in column "I" IE between 25 and 35, between 100 and 250 and 252 and 254 (in that case, I'd want Q25, Q35, Q100, Q250, Q252 and Q254) but not in column Q, which is full of values between 10 and 20000

Comment: Don't use `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` at all.  Keep track of your target row in a variable (say, `lastRow `) instead. Then it's just `lastRow = lastRow + i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have data from A2 to A202 and there are three gaps in the data. Assume also that you know the data doesn't go down to A250 and there is nothing between A250 and the end of your data.

The best way is to use `xlUp` once from the bottom rather than `xlDown` multiple times. But you can do both. Here's an example.

```
Sub LoopDown()

    Dim rStart As Range
    Dim rEnd As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rStart = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    Set rEnd = rStart 'set it to rStart initially

    For i = 1 To 7 'go to # of gaps x 2 + 1 (3 x 2 + 1 = 7 for 3 gaps)
        Set rEnd = rEnd.End(xlDown) 'every time you do an
                                    'xlDown, you reset rEnd
    Next i

    'These are the same
    Debug.Print Range(rStart, rEnd).Address
    Debug.Print Range(rStart, Range("A250").End(xlUp)).Address

End Sub
```

And returns this

```
$A$2:$A$202
$A$2:$A$202
```